# How do i make a global variable in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, global-variables

Im trying to use an if statement outside the main method of the class, but i want to declare all my variables inside the main method, how do i do this

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;
        int st = 0;
        int h = 0;

        Texts textObject = new Texts();
        textObject.TextList();

        Commands commandObject = new Commands();
        commandObject.commands();

        GUImain guiObject = new GUImain();
        guiObject.displayGUI();
    }
    public Main()
    {

        if(t == 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you almost certainly shouldn't be doing it.

But if you really want to, then you can declare your variables as `static`. If you move this

```
int i = 0;
int t = 0;
int st = 0;
int h = 0;
```

to the beginning, just after the `class` declaration, and change to

```
static int i = 0;
static int t = 0;
static int st = 0;
static int h = 0;
```

then you'll find you can access them as globals, at least from inside this package. If you declare them `public` too, you'll be able to get to them from anywhere.

But, really, you shouldn't do it like this at all. Have your `public static void main()` method create an instance of the class (`Main m = new Main()`) and then invoke some instance method on `m`. That instance method will be able to access non-static (instance) fields.

Whenever you feel the need for a global, ask yourself whether it's an indication that your code isn't structured in the right way. Most of the time (not quite all of the time) when you think you want a global, you don't really. It will just make the structural problem worse.

Comment: Thanks, my code probably won't be laid out the best but this will be my first proper project so hopefully all goes well